# Warehouses details from Snowflake metadata

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

What is the best way to get the details of the Snowflake warehouses - past and present?

I know I can do this

```
SHOW WAREHOUSES;

SELECT * FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()));
```

But it sounds odd something as foundational as the warehouse details are not covered in the metadata tables.

Also the above approach only gets the active warehouses.

I can get the list of all the warehouses (including past) from warehoue_events_history but I wont get details of multiclister etc.

Has anyone come across better approach?

Answer (score 0):

`show warehouses;` should work - I just tested it.

> Also the above approach only gets the active warehouses.

I see all warehouses, not only the active ones.

Check the docs:

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/show-warehouses#usage-notes

> Lists all the warehouses in your account for which you have access privileges.

Try running this with the role `accountadmin` in case you were using a role that didn't have access to all warehouses.

Comment: Show warehouses does work. But here are the shortcomings   a) it will only show warehouses which are currently 'operational'. If you have dropped a warehouse it wont appear. So when you are trying to join with a warehouse detail from warehouse_load_history or warehouse_metering_history there will be gaps b) developers who are trying to analyze usage patterns may not have account_admin role. They need to have access to a persistent store which has the details of the warehouses.  I was wondering if there is a work around

Comment: I got confused with the question's "active warehouses" - you meant warehouses that have not been dropped, while I thought you meant warehouses that were not suspended. I would revisit the question as a new one, focusing on exactly what kind of joins you would like with warehouse_load_history/warehouse_metering_history when warehouses have been dropped.